# Programação java com threads

Tags: java, thread

Pessoal necessito de ajuda para uma atividade:

> Considere três vetores de números.
>   Escreva um programa  para imprimir quais os maiores números Primos Gemeos existente em cada vetor.
>
> Quais os maiores numeros primos gêmeos considerando todos os elementos.
>   (Em todos os vetores)
>
> OBS: a solução deve otimizar o tempo de execução.
>        Não é permitido usar a API de Collections.

Estou com dificuldade na parte de implementação de Threads onde tenho que alocar a otimização para o tempo de execução.

```
public class NumeroPrimoGemeo {

    public List<Integer> retornaNumeroGemeos(Integer comeco, Integer fim){
        int i = comeco;
        while(i <= fim){
            if(verificaNumeroPrimo(i)){
                int x = i + 2;
                if(verificaNumeroPrimo(x)){
                    List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
                    integers.add(i);
                    integers.add(x);
                    return integers;
                }
            }
            i++;
        } throw new RuntimeException("Não há nenhum numero primo gemeos ");
    }
```

Alguém pode fazer um código e me explicar com comentários?

Comment: Está com dificuldade em qual parte?

Comment: Não é bem assim que funcione o site, jovem. Veja, [ask], como criar um [mcve] e também faça o [tour]. Tente nos explicar qual sua dificuldade e como podemos te ajudar a chegar no resultado esperado. Senão parece que você quer que façamos o seu exercício por você.

Comment: Estou com dificuldade na parte de implementação de Threads onde tenho que alocar a otimização para o tempo de execução.

Comment: public class NumeroPrimoGemeo {

    public List<Integer> retornaNumeroGemeos(Integer comeco, Integer fim){
        int i = comeco;
        while(i <= fim){
            if(verificaNumeroPrimo(i)){
                int x = i + 2;
                if(verificaNumeroPrimo(x)){
                    List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
                    integers.add(i);
                    integers.add(x);
                    return integers;
                }
            }
            i++;
        } throw new RuntimeException("Não há nenhum numero primo gemeos ");
    }

Comment: Tome cuidado que a API de Collections inclui `Arraylist`, que você está usando no trabalho. A não ser que esteja falando da classe `java.util.Collections`.